# Kafka setting default retention log and testing

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm currently trying to test the kafka retention log using a new environment with [docker-kafka](https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka).

I used `config/server.properties` and set the following for log retention:

```
log.retention.ms=2000
log.retention.check.interval.ms=2000
```

Creating a topic and adding messages to it, I would test the size of the log by going to the location of the output logs. In my case it was at `/tmp/kafka-logs/<topic-name>`. Then just `ls -l` to see size in bytes.

Adding more messages will increase size in bytes of the log file. If there is a better way to check the logs, please let me know.

Running:
`$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic <topic-name>`

I would get no config output. Log file is not deleted after 2000 ms.

On Kafka docs:

> The number of milliseconds to keep a log file before deleting it (in
>   milliseconds), If not set, the value in log.retention.minutes is used

However, setting a topic-level configuration with:
`$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic <topic-name> --config retention.ms=2000`

And checking configs on the title:
`$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic <topic-name>`

I see that the retention is set for the topic. Also, checking the log size again, it might delete the logs after 2000 ms, but it does clear within a short time.

How can I set default configurations for all topics created? Specifically related to log retention time?

Also, an additional add-on question, are there config files for each individual topic created? I'm mainly asking because I know how to set topic-level configurations via cli, but was curious to see if these topic-level configs were saved somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a server restart, global configs are used for existing topics that use default configs (no topic-level configs that overwrite my existing configs) and any new topics created after the server restart.

I tested again with another configuration (pertaining only to retention log time) and confirmed that any changes made to global configs were not being set for existing or new topics. After another server restart, the "new" global configs were set.

Comment: The global configs will be loaded up to the memory after broker startup, so any changes could only take effect after the server restart.

Comment: @Philip-Yoo - Is it still the same case in Kafka 2.2.0? Does it require the kafka restart or server restart?

Answer (score 2):

A global config `log.retention.{hours|minutes|ms} controls the default behavior for all topics. The topic-level config`retention.ms` is for individual topics.

In your case, the log did not get deleted before you set the topic-level config since the default parameter value is 7 days.

Comment: I tried creating a new topic after setting the global config file and it doesn't seem to set the default behavior for all new topics

Comment: How did you verify that?

Comment: I went to the location of the log and checked the byte size of the log file. I mentioned this in my post as well, but I did this: "In my case it was at `/tmp/kafka-logs/<topic-name>`. Then just `ls -l` to see size in bytes". Also, just to add, I'm not sure best way of doing this check, but this way seemed to do the trick at least

Comment: Ok, this is really weird but after a server restart, the global config file is being used. But any new changes to the global config file is not being considered, whether it be for existing default set topics or any new topics created after new configurations were set. Confirmed after a server restart, new configurations take place